# iOS lock screen app launch

Tags: iphone, ios, lockscreen

I would like to have my app available to launch from the lock screen similar to the camera on iOS 5.  Is this possible? If so can anyone point me to any resources to do this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible unless you jailbreak.  If you want to do it on jailbroken phones, add the jailbreak tag to your question.

Comment: Well drats.  Thank you both for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not launch your app from lock screen and it is a royal pain to do in jailbreak version as well.

Comment: Have you done it on a jailbroken version. It is turning out to be a "royal pain"